# Pandas DataFrame Resample: How to fill nan with previous "close" value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I am creating resampled minute data from a dataframe of a time series of trades and get the columns "open", "low", "high", "close", which is fine.

```
dfOHLCV = pd.DataFrame()
dfOHLCV = df.price.resample('T').ohlc()
```

My problem lies in filling the "nan"s. When there is no trade during a given minute interval, the value becomes a "nan".
Nans can be filled by applying

```
.fillna(method='ffill') # which replaces nan by the value in the previous period
```

However, the opening price in a nan cell should not be derived from the opening but the closing cell of its preceding period.

Example:

```
index | open | high | low | close
00001 | 3200 | 3250 | 3190| 3240
00002 | nan  | nan  | nan | nan
```

.fillna will fill

```
00002 | 3200 | 3250 | 3190| 3240
```

But I would like to fill like this:

```
00002 | 3240 | 3240 | 3240| 3240
```

In other words, I would like to fill the nan cells with the close price of the previous period. How could this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `fillna` with `dict`

```
df=df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(df.columns.tolist(),df.close.ffill()))
df
         open    high     low   close
index                                
1      3200.0  3250.0  3190.0  3240.0
2      3240.0  3240.0  3240.0  3240.0
```